# WPF and Very Large Images

Tags: wpf, image

Is there anything I can do to help manage the sheer amount of memory WPF uses to render huge images - potentially anything up to 10,000 x 10,000?

I need to maintain the quality as zooming is key, but loading the Image control seems to require anything from 50 - 700MB of memory usage :S

I'm not doing anything particularly clever with loading the image at the moment:

```
BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
imageSource.BeginInit();
imageSource.UriSource = new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
imageSource.EndInit();

image.Source = imageSource;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there appears to be a bit of a memory leak/issue with the networking stack as downloading the image to a local disk then loading that appears to reduce memory usage by about 40%.

All I did was copy the images down to the temp directory, System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), then load them from there. If you've got a large number of objects in your collection in your DataGrid, then it will probably also be worth using a `VirtualizingStackPanel`:

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
     VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
</DataGrid>
```

I've now read numerous blogs confirming this. I've also put in a form of lazy-load using the DecodePixelWidth/Height that Jakob mentioned but am pleased to have found a way of loading the full quality image with a considerably smaller memory footprint :)

Comment: Would you please share your solution? I am sort of having the same problem. When I load DataGrid for the first time, scrolling is really slow and sometimes it throws OutOfMemoryException. Though, after loading DataGrid fro second time, it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`BitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelheight(v=VS.100).aspx) or [`BitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth(v=VS.100).aspx) to render the image at a lower quality optimized for the size of your dialog.  In XAML it looks like this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="http://server/image.jpg" DecodePixelWidth="400" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the CacheMode way.

The cachemode way creates a bitmap version of your control at max resolution of 2048x2048. The CacheMode also load the cached bitmap in the video memory. You have some option to sets the caching behaviour.
To use it, just set the CacheMode property in your image xaml definition like this:

```
<Image Source="...">
    <Image.CacheMode>
        <BitmapCache ... />
    </Image.CacheMode>
</Image>
```

HTH
Lorenzo